# Choose first unique week in a list and then extract full date of that week

Tags: excel, date

The data in Table 1 below is the source data. The Dates were input manually and the Week # is obtained by using the formula: =WEEKNUM(*Date*;2).

**Table 1**

Week #        Date

```
36     01-Sep-17  
37     04-Sep-17  
37     05-Sep-17 
37     06-Sep-17  
37     07-Sep-17  
37     08-Sep-17  
38     11-Sep-17  
38     12-Sep-17  
38     13-Sep-17  
38     14-Sep-17 
38     15-Sep-17
```

My goal is to obtain a table as follows:

**Table 2**

Week #     Week Beginning

```
36     28-Aug-17      
37     04-Sep-17      
38     11-Sep-17
```

1. How do I get the week # in Table 2 to be the first unique week in Table 1?
2. How do I extract the full date of the first Monday related to that particular week?

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula `=SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$11=E1,$B$1:$B$11,""),1)` in cell `F1`. You must enter it as an array formula holding CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. Formula is calculating only visible days in week, so to get first day of W36 you must provide data for that day.

[image]

If you want to always get Monday date from weeknumber, then please use this formula.

```
=DATE($D$1,1,E1*7-9)-WEEKDAY(DATE($D$1,1,3))
```

Enter Year 2017 in cell `D1`. 
[image]